# Odoo - Show 404 record not found page

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am working on odoo 10. What i want to do is simply show 404 page like we show in other website if the requested page doesn't exist.

I am sending email to client and in that email template there is a link to record but some times users with upper user roles deletes that specific record due to some reason. I want to show 404 page in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can just return website page 404 according to our condition.

```
return request.render('website.404')
```

Comment: This is true for Odoo 11. However, there is a small update: it is request.render('website.page_404') in Odoo 14.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process a "real" 404, you need to render a webpage for *human users*, but you also need to return a **HTTP code 404** for software and robots. It can be useful for SEO, analytics, browser features, etc.

I don't see anything built-in in Odoo (v.16) for this purpose, but you can easily work as Odoo does within `request.render` with this code:

```
return Response(template='website.page_404', status=404)
```

With the website.**page**_404 template for actual versions of Odoo, as marked by Micha, and you just need to import the `Response` class previously:

```
from odoo.http import (Response)
```

You can check the result on the "Network" tab of your browser's tools.
[image: 404 status]